# Filter an Array by Value of Key, reorganizing it into one sub-array for each value of key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a PHP Array, which I get from a MySQL Database but that's irrelevant. Example PHP Array:

```
array ( 
    0 => array ( 
        'id' => 1, 
        'uid' => 0, 
        'file' => 'index.suf', 
        'field' => 'title', 
        'data' => 'www.webdevguru.co.uk', 
        'date' => '2014-03-22 15:39:14',
    ), 
    1 => array ( 
        'id' => 2, 
        'uid' => 0, 
        'file' => 'index.suf', 
        'field' => 'test1', 
        'data' => 'Well this is Awkward Mr Oliver Ingram.', 
        'date' => '2014-07-16 13:11:46', 
    ), 
    2 => array ( 
        'id' => 3, 
        'uid' => 0, 
        'file' => 'home.suf', 
        'field' => 'test2', 
        'data' => 'Value2.gif', 
        'date' => '2014-03-22 15:56:30', 
    ), 
);
//courtesy of `var_export()` so is valid PHP code.
```

From this I want to sort into the following:

```
array ( 
    'home.suf' => array ( 
        0 => array ( 
            'id' => 3, 
            'uid' => 0, 
            'file' => 'home.suf', 
            'field' => 'test2', 
            'data' => 'Value2.gif', 
            'date' => '2014-03-22 15:56:30', 
        ), 
    ), 
    'index.suf' => array ( 
        0 => array ( 
            'id' => 1, 
            'uid' => 0, 
            'file' => 'index.suf', 
            'field' => 'title', 
            'data' => 'www.webdevguru.co.uk', 
            'date' => '2014-03-22 15:39:14', 
        ), 
        1 => array ( 
            'id' => 2, 
            'uid' => 0, 
            'file' => 'index.suf', 
            'field' => 'test1', 
            'data' => 'Well this is Awkward Mr Oliver Ingram.', 
            'date' => '2014-07-16 13:11:46', 
        ), 
    ), 
);
```

Which basically groups them by the Value under the key of 'file', the perfectly simple code that would do this if there is only one instance of each file would be:

```
array_column($rows, null, 'file');
```

But unfortunately 99.9% of the time there is more than one, I am perfectly sure this is very easy to do in a `PHP Foreach Loop` and can manage that myself but I want as many different methods of managing what I want done, so I can test the marginal performance of each and choose whichever is best. Prior to this I had an iterated SQL Call per file, so they came out like `$output[$file] = Return from MySQLi Method.` but since am trying to improve the speed of the script as some clients may have many files, which could lead to hundreds of `SELECT` calls to gather all the information they need, instead I now use `file IN()` and gather them all simultaneously, one `MySQL Call` but then requires some playing with to get its format right. Or is there maybe some way in MySQLi to return them in the manner I want, having them grouped by the `file`.

Comment: Thanks @SBH for the reformatting!

Answer (score 0):

I have two functional foreach statements working on rather different methodologies; I would still like people to add other methods of achieving my desired output.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    global $moo;
    $moo = $file;
    $method1[$file] = array_filter($rows, function($var) { global $moo; return $var['file']===$moo; });
}
```

and

```
foreach ($rows as $curr) {
    $method2[$curr['file']][] = $curr;
}
```

After some testing on a Small Sized Result Set:

```
Method 0: 0.90606999397278
Method 1: 0.60176777839661
Method 2: 0.60173606872559

0 Being the Iterate through MySQL
1 Being the 1st Method Above
2 Being the 2nd Method Above
```